# Is the projection of function perpendicular to its residual?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For example, if I have a linear function space $\mathscr{F} =\{ \theta^Tx:\theta\in \mathbb R^p\}$, and I define the projection operator: $\Pi f =\arg
min_{g\in \mathscr{F}} ||f - g||_2^2 = \int_\mathcal{X} (f(x) - g(x))^2 dx$.

Then do I have $$||\Pi f - f||_2^2 +||\Pi f - h||_2^2=||h - f||_2^2$$, where $h$ is any linear function in the linear function space $\mathscr{F}$.

Also, if $\mathscr{F}$ is not a linear function space, does the result hold?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not understand your notation. As I interpret it you are looking at an orthogonal projection $p$ onto subspace $V$ of a Hilbert space $H$. Then you look at an element $f\in H$ and an element $h$ in $V$ or in $H$? Your question is then whether or not:
$$\\f-h\|^2 = \|p(f) -f \|^2+ \|p(f)-h\|^2.$$
The answer will be: Yes if $h\in V$, no if $h\notin V$. In general you should expect
$$\|f-h\|^2 = \|p(f)-p(h)\|^2+\|(1-p)(f)+(1-p)(h)\|^2.$$

Comment: Thanks, I think the $f\notin H$, but $h \in H$